# Importing a *package* from old Android Studio project into a new Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having difficulty Googling this.

How do I import a single java *package* (ie. subtree of java classes) from an old Android Studio project into a new one?

I don't want to import that whole old project. Or create a new one. I just want one subtree brought into my existing new project (with all the classes it contains, with their package names adjusted)

I'm trying File->New->Import Module ... but that seems to want a project with a gradle file. But I don't have a specific one just for this java package.

Comment: Copy the directory?

Comment: In the operating system? Not AndroidStudio?

If I do that, will AS automatically adjust the package names in all the files when it sees them?

Comment: Yes, I meant a simple OS copy. But unfortunately, there will be no automatic adjustment of package declarations in your IDE (at least, I am not aware of that). So my suggestion is to copy the directory into the same place as before, and then do a move refactoring from within your IDE.

Comment: Well, that seems to be as good as I can get. Cheers.